# Strange return using the "requests" python package? How to fix?

Tags: python, request, package, pip, easy-install

I had installed the python package named *requests*. (pip install -i http://pip.kennethreitz.com/simple requests)

First, I tried using the common user (*$*) but didn't worked, so, i tried the root one (#) and worked.

The problem was in the use. When I try a simple code like

```
$python
>>>import requests
>>>r = requests.get('http://www.google.com')
>>>r.content
```

I got a incridble annoying result (see this [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/AnU1uC8y).)

But using root

```
$sudo python
>>>import requests
>>>r = requests.get('http://www.google.com')
>>>r.content
```

I got the correct and reasonable result: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/aqQxsAip).

How can I fix this? This happens with **urllib.urlencode** too. (Maybe installed using sudo easy_install, but I don't remember anymore).

I tried chmod -R 777 in */usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages* and */usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages* but still with the same problem.

I really think the problem is with python packages because this codes are extremly simply.

System details:

Python 2.6.5

Ubuntu LTS 10.04.4

requests package 0.7.5

Comment: If it happens with both of those then it's not a Python problem.

Comment: Maybe its not. But, as I wrote, the code works fine. But just if using root, what is a problem.

Comment: try playing with `unicode(r.content, "utf-8")` or `r.content.encode("utf-8")` to see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your problems have to do with unicode. Try `r.content.decode('utf-8')`.

Comment: I don't know then, that's what it looked like at first glance.

Comment: @jordoex using *r.content.decode('utf-8')* I got: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: invalid data

Comment: I converted your raw pastebin paste to binary and opened it up in a hex editor, and it's strange.

Comment: @jordoex the truth is I'm not using the Google initially. This happens with other sites. Google is just an example for this question. I use python 2.6.5, Ubuntu LTS 10.04.4, requests package 0.7.5.

Comment: Yeah, from the binary dump, it looked like it could have been something that google was doing. Otherwise, the only other thing I can think of is to fire up wireshark and look at what headers you're sending, what's being received and what the difference is. My best guess is that it's a configuration setting that the requests package doesn't know how to handle properly.

Comment: @jordoex use Wireshark is an interesting ideia. Maybe this can clarify a bit the question. I'll need search how to isolate this request in wireshark, but I will take a look on this. +1

Comment: Strange thing happened. All is working again^^, don't know why. I will embrace this answer to close the question. Thx.